# An example of a lattice that's not totally ordered

Tags: relations, order-theory

The following is an excerpt from my textbook:

> A lattice need not be a totally ordered set.  Consider the partially ordered set $(ω,D)$ where D is the relation on $ω$ defined by $x D y$ iff $x | y$.  Then $(ω,D)$ is a lattice.  For all $x,y \in ω$, $inf${$x,y$} is the highest common factor of $x$ and $y$ and $sup${$x,y$} is the lowest common multiple of $x$ and $y$.  For instance, $inf${$4,6$}$=2$ and $sup${$4,6$}$=12$.  However, D is not a total order relation.

I'm confused about $inf${$4,6$}$=2$.  In the context of the example, my understanding is that the greatest lower bound of the set {$4,6$} is some element of $ω$ such that $ω \le 4,6$.  Wouldn't $4$ fit that definition and not 2?

Comment: I think you have a typo in the last line of the quote.  It should read $\sup\{4,6\}=12$  As a $\LaTeX$ hint, if you put  a backslash before operators like inf and sup, they come out in the right font.  Unfortunately, lcm does not.

Answer (score 2):

No, because $4 \not \leq 6$ by the relation we are using, which is divisibility.  $4$ does not divide into $6$ evenly.  The $\inf$ of $4$ and $6$ is the largest number which divides them both, the $\gcd$, which is $2$

Comment: Hmm.  I'm confused then about the definition of a lattice.  My textbook defines it as such:  "A __lattice__ is a partially ordered set $(A,\le)$ such that for all $x,y \in A$, the set $(x,y)$ has a greatest lower bound and a least upper bound in $A$".  I would infer from your answer that the GLB must be in relation $\le$ to $4$ and $6$, but I don't see that condition stated in the definition of a lattice that I provided, or perhaps it is and I don't see it.

Comment: Yes, the greatest lower bound has to be in relation to both elements of the set.  That is the $\leq$ in the definition.

Comment: I finally understand.  I kept on thinking that $\le$ referred to the relation of "less than or equal to", but I get it now.  There is still hope for me.

Comment: I think it is better to use some other symbol for the relation if it is not the standard less than or equal to.  Some people use $\preceq$ (written \preceq in $\LaTeX$).  Some use R as in $x\operatorname{R}y$.  It helps avoid this type of confusion.